# Coriolis effect on the nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics, coriolis-effect

[image]

Would there be a coriolis effect on the (surface) of the nucleus? Since the nucleus can be approximated as a 'liquid drop' which rotates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a quick google query “Coriolis effect nuclei” gives plenty of information on the subject. One area of interest is decoupled bands.